# Bootstrap fill blank space between cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

At first, sorry for my English.
I'm trying to create a html page with different blocks.
But when some block is taller then the other one it leaves a blank space in the height.

Already tried to make them floating, and already searched on the internet but no success.

[This is my current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM4Hb.png)

[And this is a example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUBWq.png)

I hope someone can help me.
Here is my current code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="darkContainer">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <small></small>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="lightContainer">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <small></small>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="darkContainer">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <small></small>
            <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="darkContainer">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <small></small>
            <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are using the bootstrap grid wrong. I would divide the main grid into 9 cols and 3 cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have not divided bootstrap columns properly. You have to divide it as col-9 and col-3 then place all the content inside the columns. 
Below code may work for you

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="darkContainer col-md-12">
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <small></small>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="darkContainer">
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <small></small>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="darkContainer">
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <small></small>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- col-9 -->

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="lightContainer col-md-12">
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <small></small>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- col-12-->
</div>
```

Here is the demo
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Patel_S_G/nbrnL49h/)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly you can't resolve this issue yet (only using standard Bootstrap CSS).

Maybe the Bootstrap 4 will solve this problem.

Anyway, you can resolve it with Javascript, selecting all div's inside `div.row` and set the bigger child div height to all others children.

Maybe follow example will run:

```
var divs = $('div.row > div');
var h = 0;
$.each(divs, function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).height() > h) {
        h = $(item).height();
    }
}
$('div.row > div').height(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `top` and `left` or `right` and `bottom` in CSS. This allows you to position the element any where on the page.